# should userIdInt, commentid etc be encrypted in a website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, encryption

I'm currently showing some of these commentid and userIdInt (and maybe other stuff too!) on the webpages (not directly, but if you hit "view source")... Should I encrypt them? I want to encrypt userIdIt anyway. What about commentId? What kind of id's in general need to be encrypted? Stackoverflow doesn't encrypt questionid, right? (Because it's right in the URL, but maybe it does and we see the encrypted id in URL).

If it matters, I'm using ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, the only reasons I can think of that would justify "encrypting" or otherwise obfuscating entity IDs would be:

- To avoid data leak (ex, if you have a small site, you might not want people to see that their ID is "10", implying that there are only 9 other people on the site).
- Because the server doesn't properly check capabilities, so a nefarious user changing an ID in the page source could give them access to otherwise restricted content.

There are "better" solutions to each of these problems (for the first you could just offset the user IDs by 10000, and for the second you could add the appropriate capability checks)… So I would have to say: no, you probably shouldn't be "encrypting"/obfuscating entity IDs.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you don't need to encrypt your ids.

If you see any specific security threat, you should mention it in question, but overall if you think ids will be used in form/request hijacking, encrypting them is not a solution, you need to look for a solution to prevent hijacking (google for Cross Site Request Forgery).